# How to get basic filters using Sheets API?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

According to Google Sheets API [Docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/filters#basic_filter) you can clear and set Basic filters. Is there any alternative to retrieve (list) them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all filter views using the `spreadsheets.get` method on [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get).

You just need to specify the field on the request body parameter when calling the sheets API.

```
fields: sheets/{type of filter}
```

Please see my sample code below using Google Apps Script in listing all the filter views on my Google sheet.

### Code for getting all `filterViews`:

```
function getFilterViews() {
  var sheet_id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId(); //Spreadsheet ID
  var filterViews = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(sheet_id, { fields: "sheets/filterViews" }); //Using the get method on Sheets API service
  var filterView_json = filterViews.sheets; //List the filter titles and IDs
  console.log(JSON.stringify(filterView_json,null,2));
};
```

### Output JSON:

```
[
  {
    "filterViews": [
      {
        "title": "sample filter",
        "criteria": {
          "0": {
            "hiddenValues": [
              "",
              "some_name_2",
              "some_name_3"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filterViewId": 1295199590,
        "filterSpecs": [
          {
            "columnIndex": 0,
            "filterCriteria": {
              "hiddenValues": [
                "",
                "some_name_2",
                "some_name_3"
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "range": {
          "endRowIndex": 1000,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "endColumnIndex": 1,
          "startColumnIndex": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "range": {
          "endColumnIndex": 1,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "endRowIndex": 1000
        },
        "filterViewId": 1975426417,
        "title": "sample filter 2",
        "filterSpecs": [
          {
            "columnIndex": 0,
            "filterCriteria": {
              "hiddenValues": [
                "",
                "some_name_1",
                "some_name_3"
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "criteria": {
          "0": {
            "hiddenValues": [
              "",
              "some_name_1",
              "some_name_3"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

### Code for getting all `basicFilter`:

```
function getFilterViews() {
  var sheet_id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId(); //Spreadsheet ID
  var basicFilter = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(sheet_id, { fields: "sheets/basicFilter" }); //Using the get method on Sheets API service
  var basicFilter_json = basicFilter.sheets; //List the filter titles and IDs
  console.log(JSON.stringify(basicFilter_json,null,2));
};
```

### Output JSON:

```
[
  {
    "basicFilter": {
      "range": {
        "endRowIndex": 1000,
        "startColumnIndex": 0,
        "endColumnIndex": 1,
        "startRowIndex": 0
      },
      "criteria": {
        "0": {
          "hiddenValues": [
            "",
            "some_name_1",
            "some_name_3"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filterSpecs": [
        {
          "filterCriteria": {
            "hiddenValues": [
              "",
              "some_name_1",
              "some_name_3"
            ]
          },
          "columnIndex": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

### References:

[Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

[Response Body](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#resource:-spreadsheet)

[Sheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#sheet)

[FilterView](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#filterview)

[basicFilter](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#basicfilter)

Comment: If you have any further questions, feel free to comment.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, OP wants to retrieve the list of the basic filter in Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API. In your answer, it seems that the filter views are retrieved. If OP wants the basic filter, how about modifying your answer?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @Tanaike, I have modified my answer and added retrieving all basic filters.

Comment: The documentation is lacking in my opinion. In the basic filter docs where it says you can clear and set a basic filter, it should have a note with the link for the spreadsheets.get to fetch the avaiable basic filters

Comment: I agree that the documentation should have included a link to the get basic filter method. You can also provide feedback on the documentation if you would like.